# Inject new method calls in a existing method inside a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

in ruby we can inject new methods to a current class instance

```
Class A
  def something
     pp "something"
  end
end

A.class_eval do
  def another_thing
    pp "another thing"
  end
end
```

But have a way to 'inject' new method calls in a existing method?

Example:

something after re-write he keep calling

```
pp "something"
```

but now making another call like:

```
pp 1 + 1
```

so the result is

```
def something
 pp "something"
 pp 1 + 2
end
```

Comment: You can overwrite the method as a whole (this includes decorating/wrapping a method). I don't think you can insert a line of code in the middle of an existing method body.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But you could grab a reference to the original method and call the original at the beginning or end of the replacement. So you can sort of inject code at the beginning or end of a method, sort of.

Comment: @muistooshort: yep, that's what my "decorating/wrapping a method" alludes to.

Comment: You say "block calls", but there's not a single block in sight (excluding the one to `class_eval`, naturally)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, of course you can. I do it all the time. Suppose the class is `A` and the method is the symbol `m`. Then `A.instance_method(m).source_location` gives you the file containing the source for that method and the line where it starts. Just parse the text, insert the desired code, `eval` the resulting string and [Bob's your uncle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_your_uncle). btw, is that one of Philly's white-sand beaches in the background of your pic?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry about it, i have fixed where i put "block"

Comment: @CarySwoveland: nope, that's Phuket, Thailand. Back when things were normal.

Answer (score 2):

Can you magically inject a line of code into an arbitrary location of an existing method? No. At least, not without some insane black-magic trickery that I dare not even attempt.

Can you inject behaviour *with a block*? Yes (although I'm not sure if this is really what you're asking, since none of your code snippets contain a single block). In order to do this, the original method must specify where to `yield`. For example:

```
A.class_eval do
  def another_thing
    pp "another thing"
    yield if block_given?
  end
end

a = A.new
# Invoke the "original" behaviour"
a.another_thing
# Inject your "new" behaviour at the end
a.another_thing { pp 1 + 2 }
```

Can you override a method whilst still invoking the original behaviour? Yes, this is possible using `Module.prepend`:

```
module ThingOverrider
  def another_thing
    super
    pp 1 + 2
  end
end

A.prepend(ThingOverrider)
```

Using `super` gives you the flexibility to choose *where* to invoke the original implementation, however, this doesn't let you inject functionality arbitrarily into the middle of the original method.

Comment: Sorry about it, i have fixed where i put "block"

Comment: Does this answer your question? I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by "inject new calls in an existing method", but this technique could at least be used to implement the example you gave.